# C# Getting The HTML of the Links(Content) from Website

Tags: c#, html, hyperlink

What I want is, opening a Link from a Website (from HtmlContent)
and get the Html of this new opened site..

*Example: I have www.google.com, now I want to find all Links. 
For each Link I want to have the HTMLContent of the new Site.*

I do something like this:

```
foreach (String link in GetLinksFromWebsite(htmlContent))
            {
                using (var client = new WebClient())
                {
                    htmlContent = client.DownloadString("http://" + link);
                }

                foreach (Match treffer in istBildURL)
                {
                    string bildUrl = treffer.Groups[1].Value;
                    bildLinks.Add(bildUrl);
                }
            }




   public static List<String> GetLinksFromWebsite(string htmlSource)
    {
        string linkPattern = "<a href=\"(.*?)\">(.*?)</a>";
        MatchCollection linkMatches = Regex.Matches(htmlSource, linkPattern, RegexOptions.Singleline);
        List<string> linkContents = new List<string>();
        foreach (Match match in linkMatches)
        {
            linkContents.Add(match.Value);
        }
        return linkContents;
    }
```

The other problem is, that I only get  Links, not Linkbuttons (ASP.NET)..
How can I solve the problem?

Comment: You really should use an Html Parser, like `HtmlAgilityPack`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Steps to follow:

1. Download [Html Agility Pack](http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/)
2. Reference the assembly you have downloaded in your project
3. Throw everything that starts with the word `regex` or `regular expression` out from your project and which deals with parsing HTML (read [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454) to better understand why). In your case this would be the contents of the `GetLinksFromWebsite` method.
4. Replace what you have thrown away with a simple call to the Html Agility Pack parser.

Here's [an example](http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Examples):

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net;
using HtmlAgilityPack;

class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
        using (var client = new WebClient())
        {
            var htmlSource = client.DownloadString("http://www.stackoverflow.com");
            foreach (var item in GetLinksFromWebsite(htmlSource))
            {
                // TODO: you could easily write a recursive function
                // that will call itself here and retrieve the respective contents
                // of the site ...
                Console.WriteLine(item);
            }
        }
    }

    public static List<String> GetLinksFromWebsite(string htmlSource)
    {
        var doc = new HtmlDocument();
        doc.LoadHtml(htmlSource);
        return doc
            .DocumentNode
            .SelectNodes("//a[@href]")
            .Select(node => node.Attributes["href"].Value)
            .ToList();
    }
}
```

Comment: thx 4 the answer, I will test it and give Feedback and mark the answer if it works :D